# I am unable set the footer background color full width,please check where i was wrong

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is the link:
I am unable  set the footer background  color full width / for desktop monitor,please check where i was wrong,

http://lotusvalue.in/lfinal/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a class of .`container` on an elemtn that is the parent of the footer. In Bootstrap terms, the container class limits the width of the content to 1200px (1170px with 15px gutter either side). This 1200 px bblock is then cetnered using margin: 0 auto; styling - hence the layout you are seeing with the gutters to the left and right.

To extend the footer to a full width - you need to move it out of the conaining div - apply the class of `container-fluid` to it and it will entend the full width of the viewport.

Container fluid allows the div to extend the entire width of the viewport (althought it still has 15px padding left and right so you may need to remove that. The following screenshot shows the full width footer by adding the container-fluid class.

[image]

Comment: could you please share the code,i have written in  after this <div class="contact-w3-agileits" id="contact">
<div class="container-fluid"></div> it is not reflecting

Comment: its the div after #about (the next div is a .container and contains all subsequent elements within the 1200px cetner column.) - just inspect the page using dev tools and see what happens when you change .container to .container-fluid

Comment: gavgrif not reflecting what i have tried, Could you please share the code. so that we will the code

Comment: I dont have the code - i just opened the link from the OP and inspected the contents and changed classes in the dom inspector

Comment: u mean to say this one  <div class="container"> above this div correct  <div class="footer-content-agile">

Comment: I changed this code to @media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px } to .container-fluid still no response and in <div class="container-fluid">